# How to make multiclass color mask based on polygons (osgeo.gdal python)?

Tags: python, gdal, rasterization, masking

I know how to make binary 1-band mask in python with

```
osgeo.gdal.Rasterize(src, shp_file_name, burnValues=[1])
```

But what if I have several classes and want to make 3-band mask with different colors for classes? I could manually create N binary mask and combine them, but that seems like crutch for me. Or I may manually assign values and use N Rasterize() methods. Maybe there's method in gdal, which allows you to create mask with multiple colors based by column in .shp file (class column)?

Answer (score 0):

If there is an attribute column with values to "burn" you could try the following.

```
from osgeo import ogr, gdal

vector_file = "shp_file_name.shp"

out = "output.tif"
vector = ogr.Open(vector_file)
vector_layer = vector.GetLayer()
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = vector_layer.GetExtent()
vector = None
print(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# Set the options for gdal.Rasterize() with gdal.RasterizeOptions()
options = gdal.RasterizeOptions(outputType=gdal.GDT_UInt16, outputBounds=[xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax], xRes=2, yRes=2, targetAlignedPixels=True, attribute=None) # Replace None with an attribute column with the values to rasterize

gdal.Rasterize(out, vector_file, options=options) # Set the desired x and y resolution
```